# Why cant the debugger in AndroidStudio jump to a callback?

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio

When I click onLoadFinished() and callOnLoadFinished() in Android Studio debugger why can't it jump to the source?
[image: debugger]

Answer (score 0):

Did you try F7 to step through and see what the actual error is? Once you hit you first break point you cant step in by pressing F7 to step in through each line of code after your break point